# GWT: Add a theme

Tags: eclipse, gwt, themes

I want to add a theme. So [here](http://works.sen-sei.in/gtg/help.html) there are the instructions to add a new one.

But what is exactly "Add theme.jar to your classpath"?

I'm using Eclipse.

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, you right click on your project, go to properties, and go to Configure Java Build Path.  In there, you go to "Add External Jars"[image: add external jars], and find the file on your computer.  That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but when I add the .jar file I get this error: "Updating /StockWatcher/war/WEB-INF/lib with jars from /StockWatcher/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.5.jar - unknown version' has encounterd a problem. SDK directory /StockWatcher/war' does not exist.". Anyway I refresh my browser and I expected a new color in my app, but nothing changes..

Comment: Sorry, it's working..a folder with the styles has been created in war/stockwatcher/gwt.